# Format int with negative number

Tags: c#, string, formatting

I have file that match this pattern:

```
Name-003
Name-002
Name-001
Name0000
Name0001
Name0002
```

And I need a way to format a string to have this pattern.

If I use

```
string.Format("Name{0:0000}", index)
```

It give me:

```
Name-0003
Name-0002
Name-0001
Name0000
Name0001
Name0002
```

I need a way to specify the number of digit including the negative sign character.
I want a solution with String.Format()

Comment: At least, explain the downvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look at the [documentation for numeric formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (specifically the `;` character):

```
string.Format("Name{0:0000;-000}", index)
```

... or you could learn how to use an [`if` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx) to select between two format strings based on the value of `index`.

Comment: Thanks, it's what I missed in the doc!